# Why is my attempt to fit a tanh(x) function to data not working well?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I've got data of anode currents for different anode voltages. I'm trying to fit a tanh(*x*) curve to the resulting I-V curve using `curve_fit`, but I keep getting a line.

Since I'm trying to fit a curve to *y* against log10(*x*) I did the `curve_fit` 2 ways:

1. I took the log10 of the data first and fit the curve second
2. I fit the curve first and took the log10 of the data second.

Method 1 code and output:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitfunction(v, a, b, c, d):
    return a * np.tanh(b * v + c) + d

# x data = V90
# y data = np.log10(I90)

pars, cov = curve_fit(fitfunction, V90, np.log10(I90))

plt.plot(V90, fitfunction(V90, *pars), 'r-', linewidth='3', label='Line of Best Fit')
plt.scatter(V90, np.log10(I90), marker='.', label='Data')

plt.title('Graph of Line of Best Fit of Anode Current against Anode Potential')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.ylabel('Current (A)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph using the above code was:

[image: Method 1]

Method 2 code and output:

```
pars, cov = curve_fit(fitfunction, V90, I90)
print(pars)

y = fitfunction(V90, *pars)

if any(i < 0 for i in y) == True:
    y = y + abs(min(y))

y = y[377:]
x = V90[377:]

plt.plot(x, np.log10(y), 'r-', linewidth='3', label='Line of Best Fit')
plt.scatter(V90, np.log10(I90), marker='.', label='Data')

plt.title('Graph of Line of Best Fit of Anode Current against Anode Potential')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.ylabel('Current (A)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The resulting graph using this code was:

[image: Method 2]

I'm not quite sure why in the second method, even if I do cut off the 0 values, there is still such a drastic deviation when `V90` < 0.

The part of the data that's causing problems seems to be somewhere in 2.5V-5.0V which is about 500 lines of data:

```
#Voltages(V) Currents(A) Af=89.9mA Vf=24.3V
2.50000,0.0003815846315912
2.50500,0.0003816979315912
2.51000,0.0003817056315912
2.51500,0.00038173013159120006
2.52000,0.00038178253159120004
2.52500,0.0003818257315912
2.53000,0.0003819050315912
2.53500,0.0003818466315912
2.54000,0.0003818978315912
2.54500,0.0003819977315912
2.55000,0.00038197953159120005
2.55500,0.00038198843159120005
2.56000,0.00038210623159120005
2.56500,0.00038209303159120005
2.57000,0.0003821845315912
2.57500,0.0003821863315912
2.58000,0.00038220063159120004
2.58500,0.0003822367315912
2.59000,0.00038230733159120005
2.59500,0.00038230853159120003
2.60000,0.00038232433159120005
2.60500,0.0003823070315912
2.61000,0.0003824262315912
2.61500,0.0003824784315912
2.62000,0.0003825377315912
2.62500,0.0003825299315912
2.63000,0.0003825463315912
2.63500,0.00038256423159120005
2.64000,0.00038260893159120006
2.64500,0.0003826748315912
2.65000,0.0003826939315912
2.65500,0.0003826620315912
2.66000,0.00038270823159120004
2.66500,0.00038275413159120003
2.67000,0.0003827898315912
2.67500,0.0003828730315912
2.68000,0.00038286673159120005
2.68500,0.00038290933159120004
2.69000,0.0003829376315912
2.69500,0.0003829943315912
2.70000,0.0003830041315912
2.70500,0.00038304703159120005
2.71000,0.0003830539315912
2.71500,0.0003830631315912
2.72000,0.0003831442315912
2.72500,0.00038314893159120005
2.73000,0.0003831841315912
2.73500,0.0003832354315912
2.74000,0.00038327293159120005
2.74500,0.0003833084315912
2.75000,0.0003833653315912
2.75500,0.0003834109315912
2.76000,0.00038340913159120004
2.76500,0.0003834842315912
2.77000,0.00038352123159120005
2.77500,0.00038353283159120005
2.78000,0.00038357873159120003
2.78500,0.00038351133159120004
2.79000,0.00038353613159120004
2.79500,0.0003836058315912
2.80000,0.00038369733159120004
2.80500,0.0003836595315912
2.81000,0.00038369343159120006
2.81500,0.0003837056315912
2.82000,0.0003837095315912
2.82500,0.0003837635315912
2.83000,0.0003838389315912
2.83500,0.00038387283159120004
2.84000,0.00038388863159120006
2.84500,0.00038390353159120004
2.85000,0.00038393663159120005
2.85500,0.00038400643159120006
2.86000,0.00038402783159120004
2.86500,0.0003840540315912
2.87000,0.00038411223159120003
2.87500,0.00038411843159120003
2.88000,0.0003841074315912
2.88500,0.0003841589315912
2.89000,0.00038417953159120005
2.89500,0.0003841864315912
2.90000,0.00038419383159120005
2.90500,0.0003842904315912
2.91000,0.0003843029315912
2.91500,0.0003842731315912
2.92000,0.0003843509315912
2.92500,0.0003843986315912
2.93000,0.00038439503159120003
2.93500,0.0003843986315912
2.94000,0.00038445253159120007
2.94500,0.0003844441315912
2.95000,0.00038448443159120005
2.95500,0.00038446503159120005
2.96000,0.00038451213159120006
2.96500,0.0003845723315912
2.97000,0.0003846322315912
2.97500,0.0003846078315912
2.98000,0.00038468173159120005
2.98500,0.0003846975315912
2.99000,0.00038470823159120004
2.99500,0.00038466083159120003
3.00000,0.00038470853159120003
3.00500,0.00038475533159120005
3.01000,0.00038481043159120003
3.01500,0.0003848238315912
3.02000,0.0003848566315912
3.02500,0.00038489833159120003
3.03000,0.0003848757315912
3.03500,0.0003849278315912
3.04000,0.0003849609315912
3.04500,0.0003849475315912
3.05000,0.0003850175315912
3.05500,0.0003850137315912
3.06000,0.0003850512315912
3.06500,0.0003851350315912
3.07000,0.0003850923315912
3.07500,0.0003851168315912
3.08000,0.00038514873159120003
3.08500,0.0003851388315912
3.09000,0.00038523033159120005
3.09500,0.00038527003159120004
3.10000,0.00038524373159120007
3.10500,0.00038534923159120005
3.11000,0.0003853215315912
3.11500,0.00038534393159120003
3.12000,0.0003853278315912
3.12500,0.0003853394315912
3.13000,0.0003853603315912
3.13500,0.0003853787315912
3.14000,0.00038547143159120003
3.14500,0.0003854083315912
3.15000,0.00038548693159120006
3.15500,0.00038548843159120003
3.16000,0.00038548723159120005
3.16500,0.0003855608315912
3.17000,0.0003855918315912
3.17500,0.0003855635315912
3.18000,0.0003856055315912
3.18500,0.00038563923159120006
3.19000,0.0003856708315912
3.19500,0.00038566013159120003
3.20000,0.0003857125315912
3.20500,0.00038573913159120003
3.21000,0.00038580913159120005
3.21500,0.00038580463159120003
3.22000,0.0003858180315912
3.22500,0.0003858449315912
3.23000,0.00038583533159120004
3.23500,0.00038587913159120006
3.24000,0.0003858967315912
3.24500,0.0003858645315912
3.25000,0.0003859590315912
3.25500,0.0003859778315912
3.26000,0.00038596353159120006
3.26500,0.00038597303159120005
3.27000,0.00038599453159120006
3.27500,0.0003860436315912
3.28000,0.0003860785315912
3.28500,0.0003860782315912
3.29000,0.00038609913159120006
3.29500,0.0003861384315912
3.30000,0.0003861640315912
3.30500,0.0003861927315912
3.31000,0.0003862037315912
3.31500,0.0003861900315912
3.32000,0.0003862180315912
3.32500,0.00038625343159120004
3.33000,0.00038624963159120004
3.33500,0.0003862892315912
3.34000,0.0003863312315912
3.34500,0.00038631103159120006
3.35000,0.00038635183159120004
3.35500,0.00038638793159120004
3.36000,0.0003863819315912
3.36500,0.0003864013315912
3.37000,0.00038648713159120004
3.37500,0.0003864919315912
3.38000,0.00038650973159120005
3.38500,0.0003865127315912
3.39000,0.0003865819315912
3.39500,0.0003865768315912
3.40000,0.00038658543159120006
3.40500,0.00038663733159120003
3.41000,0.00038662423159120006
3.41500,0.0003866617315912
3.42000,0.00038666563159120003
3.42500,0.0003866883315912
3.43000,0.00038664123159120006
3.43500,0.00038672403159120005
3.44000,0.0003867511315912
3.44500,0.00038671243159120005
3.45000,0.00038679173159120005
3.45500,0.00038677233159120004
3.46000,0.0003867619315912
3.46500,0.0003867944315912
3.47000,0.00038678993159120003
3.47500,0.0003868668315912
3.48000,0.00038685753159120004
3.48500,0.0003868131315912
3.49000,0.0003868772315912
3.49500,0.00038690763159120005
3.50000,0.00038699083159120007
3.50500,0.0003869496315912
3.51000,0.0003869472315912
3.51500,0.0003870432315912
3.52000,0.0003870340315912
3.52500,0.0003870396315912
3.53000,0.0003870617315912
3.53500,0.0003870569315912
3.54000,0.00038713173159120003
3.54500,0.00038711033159120005
3.55000,0.00038715503159120006
3.55500,0.00038715383159120003
3.56000,0.0003871439315912
3.56500,0.00038713713159120003
3.57000,0.00038718153159120005
3.57500,0.00038722833159120007
3.58000,0.0003871866315912
3.58500,0.0003872426315912
3.59000,0.0003872560315912
3.59500,0.00038726643159120005
3.60000,0.0003872912315912
3.60500,0.0003872947315912
3.61000,0.0003873543315912
3.61500,0.00038739643159120004
3.62000,0.0003873946315912
3.62500,0.0003874357315912
3.63000,0.00038740023159120003
3.63500,0.0003874494315912
3.64000,0.00038744203159120003
3.64500,0.00038750963159120004
3.65000,0.00038753823159120004
3.65500,0.0003876038315912
3.66000,0.0003876062315912
3.66500,0.0003876419315912
3.67000,0.00038765513159120006
3.67500,0.00038764313159120003
3.68000,0.0003876282315912
3.68500,0.0003876902315912
3.69000,0.0003876959315912
3.69500,0.0003877227315912
3.70000,0.0003877594315912
3.70500,0.0003877594315912
3.71000,0.00038777433159120005
3.71500,0.0003877194315912
3.72000,0.0003878219315912
3.72500,0.00038785143159120005
3.73000,0.0003878336315912
3.73500,0.00038787443159120003
3.74000,0.0003878839315912
3.74500,0.00038790993159120004
3.75000,0.0003879575315912
3.75500,0.0003880106315912
3.76000,0.00038798413159120003
3.76500,0.0003880049315912
3.77000,0.0003880705315912
3.77500,0.00038805773159120003
3.78000,0.0003880672315912
3.78500,0.00038812413159120007
3.79000,0.0003881292315912
3.79500,0.00038814233159120004
3.80000,0.0003881444315912
3.80500,0.0003881864315912
3.81000,0.0003881593315912
3.81500,0.0003881632315912
3.82000,0.0003881823315912
3.82500,0.00038825473159120004
3.83000,0.0003882901315912
3.83500,0.00038829763159120003
3.84000,0.0003882907315912
3.84500,0.00038834053159119997
3.85000,0.0003883670315912
3.85500,0.0003883939315912
3.86000,0.0003883834315912
3.86500,0.0003883804315912
3.87000,0.0003884391315912
3.87500,0.0003884344315912
3.88000,0.0003884836315912
3.88500,0.00038849013159120003
3.89000,0.00038856043159120004
3.89500,0.0003885616315912
3.90000,0.00038857123159120004
3.90500,0.0003886108315912
3.91000,0.0003886305315912
3.91500,0.0003886633315912
3.92000,0.00038866483159119997
3.92500,0.0003886671315912
3.93000,0.00038875213159120003
3.93500,0.0003887288315912
3.94000,0.0003887735315912
3.94500,0.0003887700315912
3.95000,0.00038872023159120005
3.95500,0.00038880303159120004
3.96000,0.0003888695315912
3.96500,0.0003888597315912
3.97000,0.00038894643159120005
3.97500,0.0003889258315912
3.98000,0.00038898183159120003
3.98500,0.0003889664315912
3.99000,0.0003889261315912
3.99500,0.00038897353159120007
4.00000,0.0003890727315912
4.00500,0.0003890072315912
4.01000,0.00038906323159120003
4.01500,0.00038904213159120005
4.02000,0.00038912523159120003
4.02500,0.0003891359315912
4.03000,0.0003891619315912
4.03500,0.0003891288315912
4.04000,0.0003892173315912
4.04500,0.0003891940315912
4.05000,0.0003892384315912
4.05500,0.0003893127315912
4.06000,0.0003893159315912
4.06500,0.0003892709315912
4.07000,0.0003892769315912
4.07500,0.0003892754315912
4.08000,0.00038935383159120003
4.08500,0.00038933983159120003
4.09000,0.00038941553159120004
4.09500,0.00038942323159120006
4.10000,0.0003894319315912
4.10500,0.0003895219315912
4.11000,0.0003895454315912
4.11500,0.00038950883159120003
4.12000,0.0003896175315912
4.12500,0.00038962773159120003
4.13000,0.0003896372315912
4.13500,0.0003896017315912
4.14000,0.0003896599315912
4.14500,0.00038967243159120004
4.15000,0.00038972243159120007
4.15500,0.00038967923159120003
4.16000,0.0003897564315912
4.16500,0.00038985093159120003
4.17000,0.0003898157315912
4.17500,0.0003898777315912
4.18000,0.00038985683159120004
4.18500,0.00038996063159120003
4.19000,0.00038990393159120005
4.19500,0.0003898995315912
4.20000,0.00039002143159120006
4.20500,0.0003900357315912
4.21000,0.00039002343159120004
4.21500,0.00039006813159120005
4.22000,0.00039010213159120004
4.22500,0.0003901114315912
4.23000,0.0003901018315912
4.23500,0.0003901289315912
4.24000,0.0003902195315912
4.24500,0.0003902076315912
4.25000,0.00039021833159120004
4.25500,0.0003902306315912
4.26000,0.00039023533159120003
4.26500,0.00039031403159120004
4.27000,0.0003903662315912
4.27500,0.00039037843159120004
4.28000,0.00039042283159120006
4.28500,0.0003903867315912
4.29000,0.00039044223159120006
4.29500,0.0003904630315912
4.30000,0.0003904529315912
4.30500,0.0003904729315912
4.31000,0.00039054473159120005
4.31500,0.0003905533315912
4.32000,0.0003905974315912
4.32500,0.0003905998315912
4.33000,0.0003906898315912
4.33500,0.00039066933159120004
4.34000,0.00039072833159120004
4.34500,0.00039076823159120004
4.35000,0.0003907929315912
4.35500,0.00039083443159120007
4.36000,0.0003908636315912
4.36500,0.00039086923159120006
4.37000,0.00039087253159120005
4.37500,0.0003908964315912
4.38000,0.0003909136315912
4.38500,0.00039098463159120006
4.39000,0.0003910287315912
4.39500,0.0003910355315912
4.40000,0.0003910477315912
4.40500,0.0003910922315912
4.41000,0.0003910749315912
4.41500,0.0003911458315912
4.42000,0.0003911830315912
4.42500,0.00039118783159120007
4.43000,0.00039116373159120004
4.43500,0.0003912555315912
4.44000,0.0003912483315912
4.44500,0.00039127843159120006
4.45000,0.0003914009315912
4.45500,0.0003913550315912
4.46000,0.00039139433159120007
4.46500,0.0003914075315912
4.47000,0.0003914602315912
4.47500,0.0003914307315912
4.48000,0.0003914930315912
4.48500,0.0003914924315912
4.49000,0.00039153143159120004
4.49500,0.00039155053159120004
4.50000,0.0003916068315912
4.50500,0.0003916372315912
4.51000,0.00039167213159120004
4.51500,0.00039174183159120006
4.52000,0.00039177053159120004
4.52500,0.00039176813159120003
4.53000,0.00039181583159120004
4.53500,0.0003918697315912
4.54000,0.00039187893159120003
4.54500,0.0003918822315912
4.55000,0.0003919370315912
4.55500,0.0003919138315912
4.56000,0.0003919716315912
4.56500,0.00039199283159120006
4.57000,0.00039201103159120003
4.57500,0.00039209833159120004
4.58000,0.00039208733159120003
4.58500,0.0003921516315912
4.59000,0.0003921233315912
4.59500,0.00039217223159120003
4.60000,0.0003922100315912
4.60500,0.0003922246315912
4.61000,0.0003922810315912
4.61500,0.00039230933159120006
4.62000,0.00039232663159120005
4.62500,0.0003923683315912
4.63000,0.00039239963159120006
4.63500,0.0003924449315912
4.64000,0.00039247533159120007
4.64500,0.0003924917315912
4.65000,0.0003925414315912
4.65500,0.0003925510315912
4.66000,0.0003926022315912
4.66500,0.00039258413159120003
4.67000,0.0003926276315912
4.67500,0.0003927253315912
4.68000,0.0003927191315912
4.68500,0.0003926767315912
4.69000,0.0003927778315912
4.69500,0.0003928117315912
4.70000,0.0003928255315912
4.70500,0.00039284933159120005
4.71000,0.00039287673159120007
4.71500,0.0003929137315912
4.72000,0.00039292833159120004
4.72500,0.00039297333159120005
4.73000,0.00039305613159120004
4.73500,0.00039298043159120003
4.74000,0.00039306123159120004
4.74500,0.00039308923159120005
4.75000,0.0003931020315912
4.75500,0.0003931107315912
4.76000,0.00039316343159120004
4.76500,0.00039320483159120006
4.77000,0.00039318313159120003
4.77500,0.0003932430315912
4.78000,0.00039328623159120006
4.78500,0.0003932948315912
4.79000,0.0003933348315912
4.79500,0.0003933708315912
4.80000,0.0003934275315912
4.80500,0.0003934933315912
4.81000,0.0003933869315912
4.81500,0.00039350763159120005
4.82000,0.00039353273159120004
4.82500,0.0003935321315912
4.83000,0.0003935798315912
4.83500,0.0003935836315912
4.84000,0.0003936641315912
4.84500,0.00039368763159120006
4.85000,0.00039365193159120003
4.85500,0.00039369873159120005
4.86000,0.0003937326315912
4.86500,0.00039382033159120005
4.87000,0.0003938480315912
4.87500,0.00039383903159120003
4.88000,0.0003938897315912
4.88500,0.0003940000315912
4.89000,0.0003939517315912
4.89500,0.0003940104315912
4.90000,0.0003940086315912
4.90500,0.0003939877315912
4.91000,0.00039403513159120006
4.91500,0.00039411413159120006
4.92000,0.0003941618315912
4.92500,0.00039414903159120003
4.93000,0.00039421843159120006
4.93500,0.00039421603159120006
4.94000,0.00039430313159120005
4.94500,0.0003943028315912
4.95000,0.0003943370315912
4.95500,0.0003943808315912
4.96000,0.0003943910315912
4.96500,0.00039442853159120004
4.97000,0.0003944494315912
4.97500,0.00039449833159120004
4.98000,0.00039456143159120004
4.98500,0.0003945686315912
4.99000,0.0003945677315912
4.99500,0.0003946011315912
```

Comment: What are the dtypes of V90 and I90? Can you please provide some test data that reproduces the issue? I wasn't able to reproduce the problem using simulated data (I used your fit-function with parameters I made up plus gaussian noise, and your method 1 recovered all the parameters correctly).

Comment: Both V90 and I90 are numpy.ndarrays. I just did method 1 using only a subset of the full data and it worked so now I'm not sure why it's not working for the full dataset.

Here the txt file of the data - https://ufile.io/6tqs3kmp
This isn't that nice of a way to share the data so if there's a better way please let me know

Comment: BTW, do you have the raw data someplace?  That could help debug this.

Comment: @asylumax Yes this link https://ufile.io/6tqs3kmp should have a txt file of the raw data

Comment: OK, but if this link goes away, others searching for this won't be able to get the data.  The data set is 1997 lines; if you ran your test with 200 lines, do you get the same error?  200 lines might not be bad enough to post, and the answer would be complete on SE...

Comment: @asylumax Alright I went through and tried to narrow down the problem region and it seems to be somewhere between 2.5V and 5.0V. I've copy/pasted the raw data in that interval into the question if it's helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of code, based on yours.  Here, there is an option to read from a file, or curve fit perfect data that is created on the fly. If you have "nice" values, like (a,b,c,d)=1,2,3,4, and take the log of the data, the curve fit does well.  However, if you fiddle with the parameters, you can wind up with bad fits, even with "perfect" data.  I did notice that when rejecting the data V<-3.0, and *not* taking the log10(I90), you get a fit that looks OK, but it isn't perfect. When trying data when V>-2.5, and taking the log of the I90 data, you get this, which isn't bad:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71008658/how-to-fit-a-tanhx-function-to-data-in-python?noredirect=1#71008658

test code to check tanh fitting

"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


def fitfunction(v,a,b,c,d):
    return (a * np.tanh((b * v) + c) + d)


# x data = V90
# y data = np.log10(I90)

# read data from file
readdata=False

if(readdata==True):
    # arr = np.loadtxt("anode_90ma_test1.csv", delimiter=",")
    arr = np.loadtxt("test_data4.csv", delimiter=",")
    V90=arr[:,0]
    # option of using raw data or log of raw data
    I90=arr[:,1]
    # I90=np.log10(arr[:,1])
    
else:
    a_coeff=100
    b_coeff=1
    c_coeff=0.2
    d_coeff=-99
    V90=np.arange(-4,4,0.1)
    createvalues = np.vectorize(fitfunction)
    I90=createvalues(V90,a_coeff,b_coeff,c_coeff,d_coeff)
    # optionally take log10
    # I90=np.log10(I90)
        

# pars, cov = curve_fit(fitfunction,V90,np.log10(I90))
pars, cov = curve_fit(fitfunction,V90,I90)
print("fit pars = ",pars)

plt.plot(V90,fitfunction(V90,*pars),'r-',linewidth='3',label='Line of Best Fit')
plt.scatter(V90,I90,marker='.',label='Data')


plt.title('Graph of Line of Best Fit of Anode Current against Anode Potential')
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Voltage (V)')
plt.ylabel('Current (A)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your answer is "you need to choose better initial guesses for the parameters"?

Comment: I don't think better initial guesses is it; I did try different values for a,b,c,d, and in the 'perfect world', I got similar issues to what the OP saw - a flat line, instead of a curve that looks like tanh().  I think the solver is OK, but I've seen issues in other problems where very small changes in your fit parameters can give results that don't look right.   Also, when eliminating some data points, the curve fit looks more like the original data.

Comment: @asylumax Alright I think I got it working - I removed some values from the data especially around the parts where there's a bit of noise and fiddled with the parameter values which produces a curve that fits well enough. I'm surprised that's the solution but thank you for the help!

Comment: I've worked on a few problems, with more exotic functions, and strange outliers and non-linearity can throw a wrench in things.  Once you have the curve fit with some of the data removed, it would be interesting to run the fit again, but using those values as starting points, to see if you *can* fit them any better.  I've used Nelder-Mead for this sort of stuff, and it can be helpful, when you have a good ballpark for the fit.

Answer (score 1):

I have to confess that I do not see any particular problem in the data and in fitting it. I'd actually say that any problems likely occur due to problems with initial values. The outliers are negligible, but one could try to use [robust fitting](https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/robust_regression.html). Start values can be guessed automatically like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

def f( x, a, b, c, d ):
    return a * np.tanh( b * x + c ) + d

def g( x, a, b, c, d, p ):
    """
    sharpen the transition to the flat part with parameter p
    """
    w = np.copysign( np.ones( len( x ) ), b * x + c )
    return a * w * np.tanh( np.abs( b * x + c )**p )**( 1 / p ) + d


data = np.loadtxt( 
    "anode_90ma_test1.txt",
    skiprows=1, delimiter=","
)

xl, yl = data[:,0], np.log10( data[:,1] )

### simple guesses for a, c and d
d0 = ( min( yl ) + max( yl ) ) / 2
a0 = ( max( yl ) - min( yl ) ) / 2
npa = np.argwhere( np.heaviside( yl - d0, 0 ) == 0 )
c0 = -xl[ npa[-1,0] ]
print ("a0, c0, d0 = ", a0, c0, d0 )

### best guess for b via differential equation
### and alternative guesses for a and d
### uses: dy/dx = u * y**2 + v * y + w
### with u = -b/a, v = 2 b / a d and w = -b/a d^2 + a b
dy = np.gradient( yl, xl )

VT = np.array([
    yl**2, yl, np.ones( len( yl ) )
])
V = np.transpose( VT )
eta = np.dot( VT, dy )
A = np.dot( VT, V )
sol = np.linalg.solve( A, eta )
print( sol )
u, v, w = sol

df = -v / 2 / u 
bf = np.sqrt( u**2 * df**2 - w * u )
af = -bf / u 
print( "d = ", df )
print( "b = ", bf )
print( "a = ", af )

### non-linear fit

sol, cov = curve_fit( f, xl, yl, p0=[ a0, bf, c0, d0 ] )
print( sol )
### with sharpened edges
sol2, cov2 = curve_fit( g, xl, yl, p0=np.append( sol, 1 ) )

### plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )

ax.plot(
    data[:,0], np.log10( data[:,1] ),
    ls='', marker='+', label='data', alpha=0.5
)
ax.plot( data[:,0], f( data[:,0], *sol ), label="round edges" )
ax.plot( data[:,0], g( data[:,0], *sol2 ), label="sharp edges" )
ax.plot( data[:,0], f( data[:,0], af, bf, c0, df ), ls=':',label="guess" )
ax.axhline( y=d0, color='k', ls=':' )
ax.grid()
ax.legend( loc=0 )
plt.show()
```

providing

```py
a0, c0, d0 =  3.9470363024506527 0.205 -7.350877976113524
[ -0.62643791  -8.42148481 -21.38742817]
d =  -6.721723517680841
b =  2.0814552335484855
a =  3.3226840415005183
[ 3.30445925  2.18844797  0.19235933 -6.7106928 ]
```

and

[image: guesses and fit]

Final non-linear fit works flawless.

Comment: Great stuff.   So, it looks like initial conditions are the key to this problem!

Comment: @asylumax yep, you almost do not need the non-linear fit.